# Powershell - how to create network adapter (loopback)?

Tags: networking, powershell, adapter, loopback

I want to create a loopback network adapter with powershell.

I can get an adapter using code like this.

```
$networkAdapter = Get-WMIObject win32_NetworkAdapter | where{$_.ServiceName -eq 'msloop'}
```

However, I cannot seem to find how to create an adapter.  The only thing I found uses devcon.exe

```
.\devcon.exe -r install $env:windir\Inf\Netloop.inf *MSLOOP | Out-Null
```

This is going to be for a windows 7 box and I didn't want to have to install some other package just to do it.  If devcon is required then is there a way to include the download and setup in the script as well?

Comment: You shouldn't have to create a loopback adapter. If you can open a command window and `ping localhost` or `ping 127.0.0.1`, you have one. If you can't, you need to look at your machine configuration.

Comment: The reason I want to create a loopback adapter is to configure multiple websites in IIS for development.  You can assign multiple IP addresses for the loopback adapter and each one can be for a different site on the same machine.  I edit the hosts file with the domain of each site I want to correspond to each ip address added to the adapter.  So basically I'm wanting a powershell script to setup the adapter for me.  I already know how to assign ips to the adapter via powershell.

Comment: @Dan this is more suited SuperUser than StackOverflow. Moreover, you do not need different IP addresses for multiple websites in development, just use virtualhosts...