# How to Add a Loopback Adapter using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry

While busily looking over Powershell 2.0 for Dummies, and Windows Powershell in Action, one of my tasks is to automate or script some repetitive computer configurations.
One of those configurations is to add a Microsoft Loopback adapter to a Windows XP box, but first, to check if it had already been installed and configured, and if not, to go ahead and do it.
Is this something that PowerShell would be best suited for, and if so, what commands, or cmdlets should I be focusing on? If you could give a sample script as a starter that would be greatly appreciated. Any links to some other useful guides would be awesome too.

Thanks in advance.

Dave

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535060/powershell-how-to-create-network-adapter-loopback)

Answer (score 2):

Someone made a script. Don't know if it is what you are looking for ->
[New-LoopbackAdapter.ps1 – Using PowerShell to create and configure a loopback adapter for use with Direct Server Return load balancing in Exchange 2010 and Lync 2010](http://www.ehloworld.com/257)

It seems to be for 2008 R2 only. Maybe the modifications to get it to work on Windows 7 are simple.

Comment: I must caution/comment that the script linked in the blog post, while great for learning, is exactly the kind you don't want to blindly run: It downloads .exe's .zips from now defunct (http) URLs and runs them.